# Check or display every possible global message

Tags: magento-1.9, global-messages

Is there a menu or page where I can check all the possible global messages? I want to translate them to Dutch and German, but I saw that not every global message is translated yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the template in which global messages are placed in magento. Either you can edit here :

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/core/messages.phtml

Or override its block file from where its coming which is here :

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php

If you are working on ubuntu, login into terminal and fire following commands, you will get all mesages :

cd magento_root_path

grep -ri 'addSuccess(' app/code/core/

grep -ri 'addError(' app/code/core/

grep -ri 'addNotice(' app/code/core/

grep -ri 'addWarning(' app/code/core/

Comment: To be honest, I was looking for a list of possible global messages, so I can translate them :p

Comment: I have updated the answer. ;)

Comment: Not working on ubuntu, im working on macOS :p

Comment: Isn;t there a simple file or database table where I can find all the global messages?

Comment: You can use same grep command for mac terminal as well. Also, all these messages are written in files, there is no dedicated table for it. :(

Comment: Hmm.. okay, well it worked :p Thanks alot